# Mobile service for Azure storage Access Policy for both Read and write

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I use the policy like this:

```
var sharedAccessPolicy = {
AccessPolicy:{
Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,

//Start: //use for start time in future, beware of server time skew
Expiry: formatDate(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10 * 60 * 1000)) //10 minutes from now
}
```

Which works well.
But if I want to generate the SAS With both READ and WRITE permissions, how should I do?

```
Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE| azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.Read
```

Doesn't work...
I'm not familiar with that SDK...
Please help~

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code here: [`https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/util/constants.js`](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/util/constants.js), `SharedAccessPermissions` is just an enum. Try the following code instead of using the constant:

```
var sharedAccessPolicy = {
AccessPolicy:{
Permissions: 'rw',

//Start: //use for start time in future, beware of server time skew
Expiry: formatDate(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10 * 60 * 1000)) //10 minutes from now
}
```

One more thing: You're using `Date`. Please note that in Windows Azure everything's in UTC so if you're in a different timezone and running the code locally, things may not work as expected.